# Giving user access to specific directories

Tags: ssh, rsync, file-permissions

I've got a new MythTV box at home and figured it would be a great opportunity to use it to do daily mirrors of my mysqlbackup directory (let's say /mysqlbackup/backups) and my website at /usr/local/apache/htdocs and below.

I figured it would be a best practice NOT to use a root login but to create a user (say dhebackup). The Myth box would rsync in as that user.

I'm not 100% up on permissions (way lower!) so I'm wondering if I need to do anything permission-wise, group-wise, etc. to give the backup user access to those dirs and sub dirs only without affecting any of the other users (root, apache, etc) that would need access to those dirs.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu file permissions indicate permission for owner, then same group, then everyone else.

So `rwxr-x---` means the owner can do all, group can read or execute, others can't access

A user can belong to one or more groups and can change group with chgrp

So what you want to do is put a new user into the groups that the file owner(s) are in for the files you want to backup ---- or make sure all logged in users can read the files you want to backup.

Comment: Great I'll start with that.